# how to iterate a function on every row that function takes inputs from various datasets

Tags: r

I have three data sets all in xts format. I have created a function that takes multiple arguments and that function takes input from these three data sets. I want to iterates this function on every row of all these data frames at once. I can do it manually one by one like i have shown in code segment but this will take a lot of time. Please suggest be better approach.

```
time_series_momentum<-function(xts.ret,xts.rank,n=1){
  # for trading the top ranked asset, replace all ranks above n
  # with NA to set up for element wise multiplication to get
  # the realized returns
  xts.rank <- as.matrix(xts.rank)
  xts.rank[xts.rank > n] <- NA
  # set the element to 1 for assets ranked <= to rank
  xts.rank[xts.rank <= n] <- 1
  # element wise multiplication of the
  # 1 period return matrix and lagged rank matrix
  mat.ret <- as.matrix(xts.ret) * xts.rank

  # average the rows of the mat.ret to get the
  # return for that period
  vec.ret <- rowMeans(mat.ret, na.rm = TRUE)


  # convert to an xts object
  vec.ret <- xts(x = vec.ret, order.by = index(xts.ret))
  f <- list(mat = mat.ret, ret = vec.ret, rank = xts.rank)
  return(f)
}

test1<-time_series_momentum(xts.ret[1,],xts.rank[1,],n=number_xts[1,])
test2<-time_series_momentum(xts.ret[2,],xts.rank[2,],n=number_xts[2,])
and so on
```

Comment: An xts object is not a data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do a slight variation in the third argument of your function.You should make this an xts object of same dimension as first arguments are. For this you can repeat columns.

```
rep.col<-function(y,n){
  matrix(rep(y,each=n),ncol = n,byrow = TRUE)
}   
time_series_momentum<-function(xts.ret,xts.rank,xts.number){
  # for trading the top ranked asset, replace all ranks above n
  # with NA to set up for element wise multiplication to get
  # the realized returns
  xts.rank <- as.matrix(xts.rank)
  xts.rank[xts.rank > xts.number] <- NA
  # set the element to 1 for assets ranked <= to rank
  xts.rank[xts.rank <= xts.number] <- 1
  # element wise multiplication of the
  # 1 period return matrix and lagged rank matrix
  mat.ret <- as.matrix(xts.ret) * xts.rank

  # average the rows of the mat.ret to get the
  # return for that period
  vec.ret <- rowMeans(mat.ret, na.rm = TRUE)
   # convert to an xts object
  vec.ret <- xts(x = vec.ret, order.by = index(xts.ret))
}
```